# Equivalent definitions of Gröbner basis and other properties linked with the division algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algorithms

I have trouble with equivalent definitions of Gröbner basis given in my course.

First we defined the division algorithm, given a monomial ordering, of a polynomial $P$ by a $r$-tuple of polynomials $(P_1, ..., P_r)$ of $K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ by recursively dividing by the leading term $LT(Pi)$ which divides the leading term of a local variable T initiated to P. This algorithm computes polynomials $(Q_1, ..., Q_r)$ and $S$ such that $P = Q_1 P_1 + ... + Q_r P_r + S$ where all the terms in $S$ are not divisible by any leading term of the $P_i$. Given in pseudo-code, the algorithm looks like :

$ Input : P, (P_1, ..., P_r) \\
Output : (Q_1, ..., Q_r), S\\
 Q_i = 0 \ for \ i = 1, ..., r \ , S = 0\\
 while \  T \neq 0 \ do :\\
  \hspace{1cm} i := 1, div := false \\
  \hspace{1cm} while \ i \leq r \ and \ div = false \ do : \\
  \hspace{2cm} if \ LT(P_i) \mid LT(T) \ then : \\
  \hspace{3cm} Qi := Qi + LT(T)/LT(P_i), T := T - (LT(T)/LT(P_i))P_i, div = false\\
  \hspace{2cm} else \ i:=i+1 \\
  \hspace{1cm} if \ div = false \ do : \\
  \hspace{2cm} S := S + LT(T), T := T - LT(T) \\
 return((Q_1, ..., Q_r), S).
$

We denoted by $\bar{P}^{(P_1, ..., P_r)}$ the remainder $S$.

We defined then a Gröbner basis $G$ of an ideal $I$ to be a family generating this ideal such that the ideal generated by the leading term of $I$ is equal to the ideal generated by the leading term of the basis.

The point is that it is equivalent to the fact that a polynomial belongs to the ideal iff $\bar{P}^G = 0$.

For showing $\Leftarrow$, I have try to apply the division algorithm to a polynomial $P \in (LT(I))$ but I have no idea what to do next.

I am also struggling with other properties of Gröbner basis given by :
$$1) \bar{P}^G = \bar{Q}^G \ iff \ P-Q \in I \\
2) \bar{(P + Q)}^G = \bar{P}^G + \bar{Q}^G  \  and \ \bar{PQ}^G = \bar{(\bar{P}^G \bar{Q}^G)^G}$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which $\Leftarrow$?  The part within the iff on the right, i.e. if $G$ is a Groebner basis and ${\bar P}^G = 0$ then $P$ is in the ideal?  Or the overall $\Leftarrow$, i.e. if for every $P$ we have $P$ in the ideal iff ${\bar P}^G = 0$, then $G$ is a Groebner basis?

Comment: I meant the fact that if (for every $P$, $P$ belongs to $I$ iff $P^G=0$), then $G$ is a Gröbner basis